# How to DRY with embed resources

Tags: rest, reactjs, dry

I am currently designing a REST API that will be consumed by a ReactJS app. The two actual endpoints are the following:

```
/species
    id
    types
        [name, name] // each specy has 2 types, contained in an array

/types
    name
```

We can see that we have an endpoint that provides a list of all the `type`resources, and the `species`endpoint provides the `type` of a particular specy.

In my ReactJS app, I am going to have a Select field that contains a list of `types` (fetched via the `/types` endpoint), and a List of all the `species`fetched from `/species`. The user will then be able to filter species by selecting a type in the Select field.

Is it still DRY to have a list of `types` maintained in the Select component, and have the list of `species` in an array of `Specy` component ? Or should I find a way to inject the `types` fetched from their own endpoint in the `specy`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have a `/species` endpoint and you create a list of all types, you have no way to cover the case where there is a type with zero species assigned to it. This may or may not be an issue. You also have to always load all species to get the complete list of types. This may be a lot of wasted bandwidth.

---

Instead, consider the following approach:

Endpoint `/types` gives you a list of all available types, which is all you initially need to fill your dropdown. Now, once the user selects a particular type, you call endpoint `/types/{typeName}/species` which gives you a list of all species assigned to type `{typeName}`. Again, you are only loading the chunk of data that the user wants to see.

Using this approach, you avoid both having to aggregate your data on the front end and having to download the complete data set before the application can fulfill its purpose.

---

Side note: the singular of species [is also species](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/species), not specy. :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and the side note !

Comment: Little morning (my time) note: Since I would like to filter species by name, isn't it better to query `/species` like this: `/species?type=xxx&name=xxx` ?